# Python: cannot import scipy.io even if scipy is installed

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, anaconda

I just want to import wavfile from scipy.io.

```
import scipy                 # this works
import scipy.io              # this does NOT work
from scipy.io import wavfile # does NOT work
```

Yes, I've reinstalled python like 4 times. Yes, I also tried multiple times to install via Anaconda. Yes, I've tried Anaconda 2.7 and 3.5. No, it does not work. Please help.

Comment: How about `from scipy import io as scipy_io`?

Comment: What does `scipy.__version__` show?  It sounds like you can have installed this via conda. If you installed it in an environment named `X` what does the `scipy` package look like here `CONDA_HOME/envs/X/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/`?

Answer (score 0):

Your scipy install is broken. It should work.

```
In [1]: from scipy.io import wavfile

In [2]: wavfile?
Type:        module
String form: <module 'scipy.io.wavfile' from '/home/br/repos/scipy/build/testenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.pyc'>
File:        /home/br/repos/scipy/build/testenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py
Docstring:
Module to read / write wav files using numpy arrays

Functions
---------
`read`: Return the sample rate (in samples/sec) and data from a WAV file.

`write`: Write a numpy array as a WAV file.

In [3]: wavfile.<TAB>
wavfile.KNOWN_WAVE_FORMATS      wavfile.numpy
wavfile.WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE  wavfile.print_function
wavfile.WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT  wavfile.read
wavfile.WAVE_FORMAT_PCM         wavfile.struct
wavfile.WavFileWarning          wavfile.sys
wavfile.absolute_import         wavfile.warnings
wavfile.division                wavfile.write
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with numpy mkl files.
Go to https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy and download the related version of numpy+mkl, then reinstall your numpy with this version.